# Copy random cells to another worksheet

Tags: vba, random, copy, concatenation, paste

(Sheet1)I have 4 columns of data, each has a different number of cells in the range.

On another sheet (SHEET2), i have 4 dropdown boxes with the names of the columns mentioned above.

When i click the command button on sheet 2, i need the code to select a random cell from the columns (sheet1) corresponding to the dropdown box selection. It then needs to copy and paste the 4 selected cells to a range on sheet 2. In addition to this, i then need to concat the 4 cells to another cell on sheet 2, with a ", " inbetween each.

Dropdown cells are in K8-K11 in sheet 2, random cells to be pasted in M8-M11 in sheet 2
Columns to select random cells from are P-S in sheet 1 (sheet2 K8=sheet1 column p=sheet2 M8 etc)

The code i have is long and clunky, i would really love to have it neatened up and running smoother, and im sure there are much better ways to do it than i have done...:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim p As Range, q As Range, r As Range, s As Range
    Dim c As Collection, d As Collection, e As Collection, f As Collection
    Dim RNG1 As Range, RNG2 As Range, RNG3 As Range, RNG4 As Range
    Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long, LastRow3 As Long, LastRow4 As Long
    Dim randomCell1 As Long, randomCell2 As Long, randomCell3 As Long, randomCell4 As Long
    Dim Names As String

    Worksheets("Contents").Activate

    ' Aoluwei's Blade
    Set c = New Collection
    LastRow1 = Worksheets("Contents").Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RNG1 = Worksheets("Contents").Range("P1:P" & LastRow1)

    For Each p In RNG1
        If p.Value <> "" Then c.Add p
    Next p
    Dim G As Long
    G = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, c.Count)
    c.Item(G).Copy
    Worksheets("Contents").Range("T2").PasteSpecial

    ' Canas Enlightenment
    Set d = New Collection
    LastRow2 = Worksheets("Contents").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RNG2 = Worksheets("Contents").Range("Q1:Q" & LastRow1)

    For Each q In RNG2
        If q.Value <> "" Then d.Add q
    Next q
    Dim H As Long
    H = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, d.Count)
    d.Item(H).Copy
    Worksheets("Contents").Range("T3").PasteSpecial

    ' Rangers Song
    Set e = New Collection
    LastRow3 = Worksheets("Contents").Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RNG3 = Worksheets("Contents").Range("R1:R" & LastRow1)

    For Each r In RNG3
        If r.Value <> "" Then e.Add r
    Next r
    Dim I As Long
    I = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, e.Count)
    Set rselect = e.Item(I)
    rselect.Copy
    Worksheets("Contents").Range("T4").PasteSpecial

    ' Abyss' Roar
    Set f = New Collection
    LastRow4 = Worksheets("Contents").Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RNG4 = Worksheets("Contents").Range("S1:S" & LastRow1)

    For Each s In RNG4
        If s.Value <> "" Then f.Add s
    Next s
    Dim J As Long
    J = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, f.Count)
    Set sselect = f.Item(J)
    sselect.Copy
    Worksheets("Contents").Range("T5").PasteSpecial
    Worksheets("Contents").Range("T2:T5").Copy
    Worksheets("Home").Activate
    Range("M8:M11").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Any help to clean this up would be awesome. I have looked all around, but can only find code to select from 1 column....

Comment: May I ask *why* you are copying random cells?  What's in these cells and why is their order not important?  Are the values or references to the cells insufficient?  Have you exhausted standard methods of randomizing information?  This doesn't seem like a very good idea, stability-wise.

Comment: Proper spacing & indentation, as well as removal of excess code (ie. commentd house code) makes a big difference in spotting errors.